# React-Native Expo & loadassetasync()

Tags: react-native, expo

If im loading images and fonts in my app.js on component mount then routing to another page, is there anything special I need to do to call those cached images? Or do I just use, for example:

```
  <ImageBackground
  source={require('../assets/images/backgrounds/sky.jpg')}
  style={styles.backgroundContainer}
  >
```

The app.js is:

```
  async _loadAssetsAsync() {
    try {
      await cacheAssetsAsync({
        images: [require('./assets/images/backgrounds/sky.jpg')],
        fonts: [
          FontAwesome.font,
          { 'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf') },
        ],
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(
        'There was an error caching assets (see: main.js), perhaps due to a ' +
          'network timeout, so we skipped caching. Reload the app to try again.'
      );
      console.log(e.message);
    } finally {
      this.setState({ appIsReady: true });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you included `assetBundlePatterns` in your `app.json`, you don't need to cache images. The images will be bundled into the app.

```
...
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
...
```